# How much to tip uber driver going out of his way to get me my phone?

Tags: usa, taxis, etiquette, tipping, uber

I was traveling to San Francisco the other day when I took an uber to my hotel, and I accidentally left my phone in the car. I got a call from the driver the next day saying he'd found it, and when I told him where I was, the uber driver actually stopped by my hotel and dropped off the phone.

I'm pretty good with American tipping, but I have no idea how much you're supposed to tip someone who goes out of their way to help a traveler. How much do you tip in a case like this?

Comment: While someone has already voted to close, and I agree it's off topic, I'd give them $20, at least... no phone, loss of info on it, cost of replacement... the driver found it and brought it back to your location? Priceless. I'd be thrilled and give them $50.